# How can we implement SignalR in Ionic App?

Tags: c#, angular, ionic-framework, signalr

I have made an app that sents messages to the users who have registered with the app(Ionic/Angular). It is getting all messages from database (SQL Server/C# API) and printing out on the message box which is good but when we are sending message to someone whom we are talking, the person is not getting message without refreshing page. For that purpose I have to use SignalR, so I need to know something in this regard that How can I implement SIgnalR with my project?

I have gone through so many tutorials but I am not getting the actual results.
Below is my Ionic/Angular page to display my SQL Server messages to the app.

```
  <div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="this.authService.allMessage">
      <p *ngFor=" let data of this.authService.allMessage">
        {{data.sendersName}}: {{data.message}}
      </p>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Now what I really want is to display messages instantly between two users. As, whenever I sent a message to someone who has already opened a message chat box with me, gets message instantly without refreshing the page.